# Magento 2: Fetch products with layered navigation programatically

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, programmatically

I want to get products with layered navigation. I found sample code for Magento 1 below. How it can be done in Magento 2 ?

http://www.credevator.com/magento-fetch-products-with-layered-navigation-programmatically/